# Watir ChromeDriver Can NOT click Element in Jenkins-AWS-Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, jenkins, automation, watir

I have the following screen
[image]
And this is my ruby steps for clicking the "STATUS" tab.

```
And(/^Click The Status Tab$/) do
# statusTab = driver.link(id: "tab3")
statusTab = driver.link visible_text: "STATUS"
statusTab.wait_until_present
if statusTab.exists?
    statusTab.click
    puts "Status Tab Clicked"
else
    fail "Could NOT locate Status Tab"
end
end
```

As you can see in my code above, I have tried using the locator "link" by 'id' and 'visible_text'.
The code above works fine in my local computer. I have tried running it using chromedriver and chromedriver in headless mode. I have tried using Jenkins in my local computer, too.

But, it failed when running it in Jenkins server in the AWS.
I got the following error in my cucumber report:
[image]

```
unknown error: Element <em>...</em> is not clickable at point (146, 16). Other element would receive the click: <li>...</li>
```

(Session info: headless chrome=62.0.3202.62)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1039-aws x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Is there a way to tackle this issue?

Comment: why did you tag this question for Watir?  I see no watir code above, what I see looks like webdriver code.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden All of them are WATIR code, clearly WATIR code! he used the variable driver instead of b, that's all. look at the function he has called, `link`, `wait_until_present`

Comment: @FMD, does your page use a responsive/adaptive design? If you make your browser smaller locally, does it still work?

Comment: OH, I see...  had to expand the screenshots to see the actual code. (which is not readable when viewing the main question..  I saw the error he included and that was enough to know what was going on.    as an aside, Since 'driver' is the convention for webdriver, I think we ought to discourage using that as the name for the browser object when coding in Watir.. (I mean clear people can do what they like, but it does cause confusion and makes one think it's a webdriver 'driver' object )

Comment: @JustinKo yuph. it works okay on my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time that something works in a real browser, but not headless is due to a difference in the size of the actual browser window.  Headless seems to open in a smaller window, which can cause two things to happen

1) element may be off-screen  and can't be scrolled to for some reason

2) (especially typical of reactive sites that arrange to fit space allowed) the site ends up arranged such that another element is covering the one you are trying to click.

The clue to which is the case is usually in the error message.  In your case the text `Other element would receive the click` is telling you that something else has covered up the thing you are trying to click on.

Try setting the browser window size right after you create your browser/driver object.  If you are using Watir the command usually looks something like this

```
browser.window.resize_to(1024, 768)
```

Generally I talk to the PO and ask what the minimum supported screen size (assuming a maximized browser window) is, and set the browser to that size.  Often if tablet browsing is to be supported without a special mobile site, the smallest supported screen size will beo 1024x786 or 768x1024 (depending if portrait or landscape orientation is assumed)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I have tried that command and check the window size by using

size = driver.window.size
puts "The browser window is #{size.width} wide by #{size.height} high"

And, the window size stuck on 800x600...

Is there any other way for resizing the window size?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless size can be specified as a parameter/property when first creating the browser object, the b.window.resize_to method is the only way I know.   You could try using `browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to` to call the webdriver method more directly, but I expect that is exactly what Watir itself is calling so I would not expect any difference (file a bug if there is).
Does this problem happen with all browsers, or just a particular flavor?  Is your browser and the appropriate 'driver' (e.g. chromedriver) completely up to date?